# zsh get numbered log files in backwards order

Tags: files, zsh, brace-expansion

I have rolling log files that are numbered such that most recent queries are in `x.log` until that file hits a threshold size, then it's renamed to `x.log.1` and a new `x.log` starts.

I am writing a basic parser that goes through these files to extract some information, in chronological order. Which means I need to read the files in backwards order. So start with file `x.log.10` process it line by line, then `x.log.9` etc. until I finally process `x.log` which has the latest log entries.

I have a small python script for this purpose, I am just wondering how to invoke the command on the zsh CLI. I know I can use brace expansion `x.log.{10..1}` but naturally this would not include the most recent file `x.log`

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the actual file mtime (which you can do in zsh via the `(Om)` glob qualifier)?

Comment: @steeldriver interesting idea, I had not thought of that. How would that work in practice?

Comment: I've added a brief illustration below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zsh has *glob qualifiers* that may be used to modify the sort order. So for example, you could use

```
 print -rl x.log*(nOn)
```

to print the files with the **n**umeric glob flag enabled (`n`), **O**rdered by **n**ame (`On`). This appears to place the non numeric `x.log` last in my locale.

Alternatively, instead of relying on the numeric order of the names, use the files' actual **m**odification times:

```
print -rl x.log*(Om)
```

You may wish to add the `N` (null glob) qualifier as well. See `man zshexpn` for details.

Comment: Hmm I get `zsh: unknown file attribute: 0` in both cases

Comment: @posdef it should be letter `O` not digit `0`

Comment: If you add `N`, you'll probably want to use `print -rC1` instead of `print -rl` as well. I'd recommend `info zsh qualifiers` (and possibly install `zsh-doc`) instead of `man zshexpn`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks - my assumption is the OP will be using the glob in a shell loop like `for log in x.log*(Om)` so the `print` was only intended for illustration here